# How to make every cell in a column display the instances of a string from that cell's respective row without hardcoding the row number

Tags: excel, variables, dynamic, countif

I have an attendance list with a list of names in the first column, and dates in the first row, with an "x" marking the dates someone attended.  I'd like to make one of the columns display the total number of times an "x" appears in that row, without needing to change the row number in each cell(I'd like to reference the current row as a variable I guess).

The following works:
=COUNTIF(E2:Z2, "x")

but I'd like something more like this:
=COUNTIF(ROW()2:ROW()2, "x")

I would also like a similar way to reference the current column dynamically.  I'm OK with needing to paste the same equation in each cell of the row/column if necessary, but if there's a way to highlight an entire row and do something like "for each cell in this row, get the current column and count the instances of "x" that would be most ideal.

I have almost no experience with excel, but I'm a developer as a profession so this stuff at least makes sense to me.  Any help would be appreciated

Thanks in advance for any responses!

Answer (score 0):

This formula counts "x" in the entire second row:

```
=COUNTIF(2:2,"x")
```

To count the "x" in column B the formula would be

```
=COUNTIF(B:B,"x")
```

When you copy it, the row/column values will adjust.